# how to print form fields in the next page?

Tags: python, django

models.py
I have created a Model i.e Form_db,now i want to print that information using template thanks.html

```
from django.db import models
from django import forms

# Create your models here.


class Form_db(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=50)
    number = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    any_query = models.TextField(blank=True,max_length=100)
    address = models.TextField(max_length=100,blank=True)

    def __str__(self):  # __unicode__ on Python 2
        return self.name
```

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from .models import Form_db
class Form_db_att(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Form_db
        fields= ['name','email','address','number','any_query']
```

**views.py**

```
    from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect, HttpResponse, request
    from django.shortcuts import redirect ,render
    from .forms import Form_db_att
    from django.utils import timezone
    from .models import Form_db
    # Create your views here.

    def home(request):
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = Form_db_att(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                model_instance = form.save(commit=False)
                model_instance.timestamp = timezone.now()
                model_instance.save()
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/home/test')
        else:
            form = Form_db_att()
            return render (request,'mforma/name.html',{'form':form})

def thanks(request):
    form = Form_db(request.POST)
    return render(request,'mforma/thanks.html',{'form':form})
```

thanks.html
form.id is returning values with csrf token and presenting the field values in list format.

```
<form action="" method="post">
{{form.id}}
</form>
```

**name.html**

```
<form action="/home/thanks/" method="post" >
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{form.as_p}}
<input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

**mformp/urls.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf.urls import url , include

urlpatterns = [
    url('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url('home/',include('mforma.urls')),
]
```

**mformp/urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views
urlpatterns =[

    url(r'^$',views.home,name='home'),
    url(r'^thanks/$',views.thanks,name='thanks')
]
```

Comment: Please use [CapWords](http://pep8.org/#class-names) naming convention.  Your `Form_db` should be `FormDb`like that...

Comment: Where you're redirecting your user to `thanks.html` ?

Comment: i am not redirecting the information but getting that model information to be posted on page home/thanks

Comment: My question is how you are showing the thanks.html after the form submit. I'm not seeing any where you're calling the thanks url ( redirect or render )

Comment: That is in views after clicking submit it is redirected to home/thanks,in views the template is rendered in home function and thanks.html is rendered in thanks function in views

Comment: Well you're not showing the code render to thanks.html after the form submit. Would you?

Comment: no but i want to post the data collected by the form into next page after submission

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the form.save render thanks.html with saved model context.

```
model_instance.save()
return render(request, 'thanks.html', {'form': form})
```

thanks.html

In this thanks page just print all the fields by `{{ form }}`.

Comment: yes it is working but only name filed value is printed.

Comment: Yes that's right it will print only name field because in your Form_db class you have constructed the __str__ to `self.name` remember ?

Comment: If you want to print `email` then do `{{ model_instance.email }}`

Comment: how can we do that if we have more fields .it requires to type {{model_instance }} for every field

Comment: yes if you want to display email or number then you have to type it. What is wrong with this approach ?

Comment: if i have 50 fileds or more then typing {{model_instance}} for 50 times in the template